# How i create i deep relation in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, migration, laravel-migrations

I want to make a relation between teacher, class, and student. A teacher has only one class and each class have many students. My question is that which relation I use Laravel to create this relation?

Comment: Are you wanting to access students straight from the teacher model? Or access them in order from teacher->class->students ?

Comment: ^ You can do both of those things in Laravel, with the same Models and Relationships. @SheikhHammad, what is the actual question here? Have you tried setting this up and had difficulty? If you're looking for a recommended Database structure, then maybe https://dba.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask. If you're looking for us to write the Migrations, Models and Relationships for this, then you're in the wrong place, as Stackoverflow is not a free coding service.

Comment: @Andy, I want to access them in order

Comment: @SheikhHammad, Ok. Can you share the relationship code in each of those models? It's hard to know what might be going wrong without seeing what you have attempted already. You might want to take a look at this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Before you use Laravel, you should understand about database relations first. If you use Laravel without basic, later you will be confused without Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read eloquent relationships doc to find the solution :
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Some tips :

A teacher can have only one class so it is a one to one relation :
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Classes can have many students so it is a one to many relation :
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

> if students can belong to many classes, it's not an one to many relation but a many to many relation : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

If you want more help, don't hesitate to ask me !

(i am french so sorry if my english is bad)